# How to mimic this material layout perfectly

Tags: android

[image]

I am trying to mimic the above notification layout design. I am struggling to get it right.

```
  <LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:id="@+id/layout"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="80dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:padding="10dp">
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/toplayout"
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="20dp"
            >
        </RelativeLayout>
        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlleft"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="left">
    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/image"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_marginRight="10dp"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_launcher"
      />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing"
        android:id="@+id/title"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        />
    <TextView
        android:textSize="13dp"
        android:textColor="#000"
        android:text="Testing is awecome"
        android:id="@+id/body"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_toRightOf="@id/image"
        android:layout_below="@id/title"
        />
        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:id="@+id/rlRight"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:gravity="right">
            <ImageView
                android:id="@+id/cancel"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:gravity="right"
                android:layout_marginRight="20dp"
                android:src="@drawable/reply_icon"
                />
      
        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
```

Comment: The view you have added is from an OS, not a remote view. You can't make remote view exactly the same as what is shown in the image. there will be difference based on different manufacturers.  And I also don't recommend you to create custom remote views for notifications because they behave differently on different devices

Comment: @AgentP To avoid this as you mentioned, is there any way to layout action buttons to the right in a notification?

Comment: https://developer.android.com/training/notify-user/expanded I would recommend you to check this out... it has some hints on notifications and nice documentation